# How to combine two galleries that act as one with the same column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables with same structure:

```
    //gallery
id | user_id | image | type
    //gallery_default
id | user_id | image | type | folder
```

In "*gallery*" table i save uploaded images from users and in "*gallery_default*" I save predefined images from server (image name and folder like type).

I whant to join 2 tables that act as one with the same column name and same type.

**EXAMPLE**

```
(SELECT `image`, '1' AS `t` 
 FROM `gallery` 
 WHERE `user_id`='".$u->get('id')."' 
 AND `type` LIKE 'type1' 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)

UNION

(SELECT `image`, '2' AS `t` 
 FROM `gallery` 
 WHERE `user_id`= '" . $u->get('id') . "' 
 AND `type` LIKE 'type2' 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)

UNION

(SELECT `image`, '3' AS `t` 
 FROM `gallery` 
 WHERE `user_id` = '" . $u->get('id') . "' 
 AND `type` LIKE 'type3' 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)

UNION

(SELECT `image`, '4' AS `t` 
 FROM `gallery` 
 WHERE `user_id` = '" . $u->get('id') . "' 
 AND `type` LIKE 'type4' 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)

ORDER BY `t` ASC 
LIMIT 8
```

-This work for one "*gallery*" table, but how do I add a second "*gallery_default*" to act as part of the first.

Comment: If you can't do it mysql way, why dont you do it php way, just do the same above with second table, take results with php, save them in array and use rand() to show them

Comment: Yes that is easy way but I just whant to do that with mysql if exist chance becouse is faster.

Comment: It's absolutely possible!
Use the same UNION syntax : 

`UNION (SELECT CONCAT(folder, '/', image) AS image, 5 AS t) FROM gallery_default WHERE some_condition` ...

Please note that all queries should return same fields number in order to use UNION

Comment: @php-dev  I misspoke when I was writing. I whant to join 2 tables that act as one with the same column name and same type.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić Is the `t` field mandatory? In other words, what is this field for?

Comment: @php-dev Yes it is, I use that to order images. But I can use ORDER BY `type`. JTC give me interesting solution

Comment: Even @JTC idea is working and acceptable, check my answer as an alternative ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

This query should work for you :

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT image, type, 1 AS t FROM gallery
  UNION
  SELECT image, type, 2 AS t FROM gallery_default ORDER BY RAND()
) AS all_galleries
GROUP BY type, t
```

The idea is to combine both results into a derived table, then `GROUP` results by type, and t. This will ensure that will get 2 images per type, one from `galleries` and one from `default_galleries`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes this is better becouse it save time and I don't need to create temp table. Is betters solutin. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Perhabs u subquery should be sufficient:

```
SELECT image, 
(SELECT image FROM table2 WHERE type LIKE 'typeX' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as image2
FROM gallery 
WHERE ....
```

It's not usable code, but I think it shows course of approach nicely enough.

Also dont use this mysql `RAND()`, http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Based on your comment:
You should merge two tables into one temporary, take from it, what you want then drop it.

So something like:

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT * FROM gallery UNION SELECT * FROM gallery_default
```

To avoid duplicite id simply now use : `ALTER TABLE temp drop id;`

At this time you should have table temp which contains both tables.
Now you should use your query to get desired results.

Then drop it:

```
DROP TABLE temp
```

Comment: I'm not following, I figured, that you want 2 random images from 2 tables

Comment: No. I whant to join 2 tables that act as one with the same column name and same type. Rand is not immportant for now. I correct expanation now.

Comment: I will try this. When I geta all data to drop table. Right? Thanks!

Comment: Question, how to prevent duplicate ID's?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65398/discussion-between-ivijan-stefan-stipic-and-jtc).